# Quotient groups and homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $f\colon G\to H$ be a homomorphism of groups such that the restriction of $f$ to $N$ is an isomorphism $N\cong H$. Prove that $G \cong N \times K$, where $K$ is the kernel of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Given $g\in G$, $f(g) \in H$. So since $f|N$ is a surjection of $N$ onto $H$, there exists an $n \in N$ such that $f(n) = f(g)$. Thus $f(n^{-1}g) = f(n)^{-1}f(g) = f(g)^{-1}f(g) = e$, showing that $n^{-1}g \in K$. So $n^{-1}g = k$ for some $k \in K$. Then $g = nk \in NK$, and consequently $G = NK$. If $x\in N \cap K$ then $x\in N$ and $f(x) = e$. By injectivity of  $f|N$, $x = e$. Therefore $N \cap K = \{e\}$. Furthermore, given $k \in K$ and $n \in N$, $f(knk^{-1}) = f(k)f(n)f(k)^{-1} = ef(n)e^{-1} = f(n)$. Since $N$ is normal in $G$, $knk^{-1} \in N$. So the equation $f(knk^{-1}) = f(n)$ and injectivity of $f|N$ implies $knk^{-1} = n$, or $kn = nk$. In summary, we have

1. $G = NK$
2. $K \cap N = \{e\}$.
3. $kn = nk$ for all $k \in K$ and $n\in N$.

Properties 1., 2., and 3. imply that $G \cong N\times K$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific example of a more general theorem:

> **Theorem**
>   Let $N,K$ be normal subgroups of $G$ such that $\{nk\,:\,n\in N,k\in K\}=G$ and $N\cap K=\{1\}$. Then $G\cong N\times K$.

**Proof**
Note that $nk=kn$ for all $n\in N,k\in K$. Indeed, $nkn^{-1}k^{-1}=(nkn^{-1})k\in K$ since $K$ is normal and $nkn^{-1}k^{-1}=n(kn^{-1}k^{-1})\in N$ since $N$ is normal, so $nkn^{-1}k^{-1}=1$ as claimed. Define $\phi(n,k)=nk$ for $n\in N,k\in K$. We have
$$\phi((n_1,k_1,)(n_2,k_2))=\phi(n_1n_2,k_1k_2)=n_1n_2k_1k_2=n_1k_1n_2k_2=\phi(n_1,k_1)\phi(n_2,k_2)$$

so $\phi:N\times K\rightarrow G$ is a homomorphism. We know the image of $\phi$ is $\{nk\,:\,n\in N,k\in K\}=G$, and if $(n,k)\in\ker\phi$ then $n=k^{-1}\in N\cap K$, so $n=k=1$ and hence $\ker\phi$ is trivial. Hence $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

In this case, we are given that $N$ is normal in $G$ and $K$ is the kernel of a homomorphism so is also normal. Since $f|_N$ is an isomorphism, for every $g\in G$ there exists $n\in N$ such that $f(g)=f(n)$. This implies $f(gn^{-1})=1$, so $gn^{-1}\in K$ and hence $g\in nK\subset\{nk\,:\,n\in N,k\in K\}$. This completes the proof.